# How to Vectorize this pandas apply function that uses other column values as new column names

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a dataframe that I would like to add new columns with names from one column ("purchase") and values from another ("amount"). I know how to do it with DataFrame.apply(), but how can I vectorize it and make the code faster (on the bigger dataframe that I am actually working with)? Thanks!

Edit: the "obs" column is unique.

Example Input:

| obs | purchase | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Coffee | 1 |
| 2 | Juice | 1 |
| 3 | Coffee | 2 |

Example Output:

| obs | purchase | amount | Coffee | Juice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Coffee | 1 | 1.0 | NaN |
| 2 | Juice | 1 | NaN | 1.0 |
| 3 | Coffee | 2 | 2.0 | NaN |

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

obs = [1, 2, 3]
purchase = ["Coffee", "Juice", "Coffee"]
amount = [1, 1, 2]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"obs": obs, "purchase": purchase, "amount": amount})

def get_amount(row):
    row[row[f"purchase"]] = row[f"amount"]
    return row

df = df.apply(get_amount, axis=1)
```

Comment: Is "obs" always unique? If not, can you update the example?

Comment: yes, "obs" is unique in my application. I will update the question, thanks!

Comment: Then have you tested if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72121580/16343464) does what you want?

Comment: yes, I tested and it works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming unique obs, you can `pivot` and `merge`:

```
df2 = df.merge(df.pivot('obs', 'purchase', 'amount'), on='obs')
```

Output:

```
   obs purchase  amount  Coffee  Juice
0    1   Coffee       1     1.0    NaN
1    2    Juice       1     NaN    1.0
2    3   Coffee       2     2.0    NaN
```